# Sublime text : Add css3 syntax highlighting

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

Is it possible to add css3 properties like : "*animation-name*", "*animation-timing-function*", or values like : "*display-table*" in CSS syntax highlighting.

I guess it implies *css_completions.py* but I don't know how to proceed.

http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/4408/54ki.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily you're not the first one to have this question, and this guy has made a package that does just that: 
https://github.com/i-akhmadullin/Sublime-CSS3

At the bottom there's a installation-guide using the package manager.

Comment: That package hasn't been updated since October 2014. My CSS3 package is currently the [53rd most popular package on Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3). It's comprehensive and current with the latest W3C specs. It's also written in [the new, improved sublime-syntax format](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html).

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: My CSS3 package is no longer maintained and most people would be better served by using the default CSS package that ships with Sublime. It may still be useful in flagging deprecated/bad CSS, however.

I just pushed what I hope will be [the definitive CSS3 package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS3) on Package Control. It's for Sublime Text 3 only, but it has comprehensive support for CSS3 properties, values, @-rules, etc. It also has a full set of completions for each property.

Try it out. If you have any problems, please open an issue on [Github here](https://github.com/y0ssar1an/CSS3/issues).

Comment: Very nice, but what if I use CSS in the <script> tag?